# Experiencing compile error with a higher order component's mapState function that returns an object within an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

**30/11/2019**
Updated the code sandbox with the solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/witherrorlistener-and-withid-hoc-components-the-version-that-compiles-207sg).

**Original Question asked on 28/11/2019**
I am trying to learn Higher Order Components but struggling to get a Higher Order Component connected to the redux store and router.  Hoping that someone can help with a Higher Order Component type compilation problem I am struggling with relating to *mapStateToProps*.

I am trying to create a higher order component, [*withErrorListener*](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-routed-connected-hoc-v2joz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fhigher-order-components%2FwithErrorListener.tsx&theme=dark). It has the following features:

1. *withErrorListener* wraps a base component that has the *uniqueId property*. The uniqueId property is created by another Higher Order Component, [*withId*](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-routed-connected-hoc-v2joz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fhigher-order-components%2FcomponentId%2FwithId.tsx&theme=dark).
2. *withErrorListener* returns a wrapper class component that listens on the redux store and filters errors notified for that the base component. If there are no errors to display it renders the base component. I am filtering errors in redux state using *mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) => StateProps*, where `StateProps = { error: IApiFailure[]}`
3. *wthErrorListener* renders the errors and dispatches a _clear_error_ action when the component is unmounted by clicking home button on error rendered page. This means that the higher order component also requires *RouterComponentProps* dependency.

It is intended to be  used as follows `NewComponent = withErrorListener(withId(BaseComponent))`.

The problem that I am encountering is that Typescript raises the compile error that  type *IApiFailure* cannot be found in the *ErrorListener* HoC class when it is assigned to the react-redux *connect* function. IApiFailure is a type contained within the StateProps return type for the mapStateToProps function. The only way that I can get it to compile is to cast to the *any* type.

The HoC is connected to the store with the following code snippet below. The full code for the HoC  ErrorListener class can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-routed-connected-hoc-v2joz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fhigher-order-components%2FwithErrorListener.tsx&theme=dark). I have also included the error information below ...

Subsequently, I cannot connect the connected component to the withRouter function.
If I cast the Hoc ErrorListener to any type in the connect function, then compilation succeeds but the uniqueId property in [OwnProps is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075397/mapstatetoprops-ownprops-argument-contains-a-property-that-is-undefined-in-highe). This is used to filter the error store.

```js
  /**
   * Redux properties
   */
  type StateProps = {
    error: FailureNotify[];
  };

  /**
   * Function to return subset of store state that filters errors for the wrapped component via uniqueId property
   * @param state  The root state
   * @param ownProps  Properties passed to wrapped component according to `https://react-redux.js.org/next/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#ownprops-optional`
   * @returns  StateProps type that contains a list of filtered errors of type FailureNotify.
   */
  const mapStateToProps = (
    state: RootState,
    ownProps: HocProps 
  ): StateProps => {
    console.log(`withErrorListener mapStateToProps => ${ownProps.uniqueId}`);
    return {
      error: filterErrors(state.errors, ownProps)
    };
  };

  const dispatchProps = {
    clearError: clearErrorAction
  };

  /**
   * Type declarations
   */
  type TStateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
  type TDispatchProps = typeof dispatchProps;
  type HocProps = BaseProps & TStateProps & TDispatchProps;

const ConnectedHoc = connect<
    TStateProps,
    TDispatchProps,
    ExpectedProps,
    RootState
  >(
    mapStateToProps,
    dispatchProps
  )(ErrorListener); // this raises the error below...unless I cast it as any

  return ConnectedHoc;
  // const RouteHoc = withRouter(ConnectedHoc);

  // return RouteHoc;
```

The compile error that I receive is below. I think typescript is not recognising the type embedded **within** the type returned by mapStateToProps, i.e. IApiFailure[] type is unrecognised in *HocProps*. Is this not automatically achieved when using `ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>`?

```
Argument of type 'typeof ErrorListener' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<StateProps & { clearError: (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<constants.CLEAR_ERROR, ClearError>; }, HocProps>>'.
  Type 'typeof ErrorListener' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Matching<StateProps & { clearError: (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<constants.CLEAR_ERROR, ClearError>; }, HocProps>, any>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'Matching<StateProps & { clearError: (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<constants.CLEAR_ERROR, ClearError>; }, HocProps>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<HocProps>'.
        Type 'P extends "error" | "clearError" ? (StateProps & { clearError: (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<constants.CLEAR_ERROR, ClearError>; })[P] extends HocProps[P] ? HocProps[P] : (StateProps & { ...; })[P] : HocProps[P]' is not assignable to type 'HocProps[P]'.
          Type 'HocProps[P] | ((StateProps & { clearError: (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<constants.CLEAR_ERROR, ClearError>; })[P] extends HocProps[P] ? HocProps[P] : (StateProps & { ...; })[P])' is not assignable to type 'HocProps[P]'.
            Type '(StateProps & { clearError: (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<constants.CLEAR_ERROR, ClearError>; })[P] extends HocProps[P] ? HocProps[P] : (StateProps & { ...; })[P]' is not assignable to type 'HocProps[P]'.
              Type '(StateProps & { clearError: (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<constants.CLEAR_ERROR, ClearError>; })[P] | HocProps[P]' is not assignable to type 'HocProps[P]'.
                Type '(StateProps & { clearError: (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<constants.CLEAR_ERROR, ClearError>; })[P]' is not assignable to type 'HocProps[P]'.
                  Type 'StateProps & { clearError: (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<constants.CLEAR_ERROR, ClearError>; }' is not assignable to type 'HocProps'.
                    Type 'StateProps & { clearError: (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<constants.CLEAR_ERROR, ClearError>; }' is not assignable to type 'BaseProps'.
                      Type '(FailureNotify[] extends HocProps["error"] ? HocProps["error"] : FailureNotify[]) | ((fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<any>, navigateTo?: string) => PayloadAction<...> extends HocProps["clearError"] ? HocProps["clearError"] : (fromAction: string, fromComponent: string, history?: History<....' is not assignable to type 'HocProps[P]'.
                        Type 'FailureNotify[] extends HocProps["error"] ? HocProps["error"] : FailureNotify[]' is not assignable to type 'HocProps[P]'.
                          Type 'FailureNotify[] | HocProps["error"]' is not assignable to type 'HocProps[P]'.
                            Type 'FailureNotify[]' is not assignable to type 'HocProps[P]'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: Updated the code sandbox with the solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-development-fork-207sg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FApp.tsx&theme=dark) to help others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're injecting Props by using `mapStateToProps` and `dispatchProps` in a `connect` you have to subtract these props from the `BaseProps` generic type by using the `Diff` helper type.
Moreover, if you want to use these injected Props in the `Hoc` component you have to pass them as the Component type argument. e.g. `React.Component<InjectedProps>`.

This is a reason for the errors.

So in your example props are:

```
type InjectedProps = TStateProps & TDispatchProps;

type HocProps = Diff<BaseProps, InjectedProps>;

class Hoc extends React.Component<InjectedProps> { ... }

const ConnectedHoc = connect<
    TStateProps,
    TDispatchProps,
    HocProps,
    RootState
  >(
    mapStateToProps,
    dispatchProps
  )(Hoc);
```

Also, please check the same discussion in the [react-redux-typescript-guide](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide/issues/195)

Comment: Thanks again for your help, appreciated :) As usual, very helpful and some very useful material for understanding react-redix with typescript in the guide. Also finding your [typesafe-actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions) library very useful.